# How to repeat an array in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

How to `ng-repeat` an array in angular, I want to loop `gpa` in my view.

```
   [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Pre-Algebra",
    "selected": true,
    "gpa": [
      {
        "grade_date": null,
        "grade_type": null,
        "grade_percent": null,
        "letter_grade": null
      },
      {
        "grade_date": null,
        "grade_type": null,
        "grade_percent": null,
        "letter_grade": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Pre-Calculus",
    "selected": true
  }
]
```

**View  Code:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="course in ctrl.subjectCourseGrades| filter: {selected  : true} track by $index">
 <table class="academy-table gpa-table" ng-class="!ctrl.editAcademyToggle?'data-view':''">
        <tr ng-repeat="gpa in course.gpa" ng-if="!ctrl.editAcademyToggle" class="ots-data">
            <td>
                <b>Id is  : {{$index}}<span ng-bind="gpa.grade_date"></span></b>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
    </div>
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `$index` in the ngRepeat expression

*Use*

```
<tr ng-repeat="gpa in course.gpa"
```

*instead of*

```
<tr ng-repeat="gpa in course.gpa[$index]"
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.subjectCourseGrades = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Pre-Algebra",
    "selected": true,
    "gpa": [{
        "grade_date": null,
        "grade_type": null,
        "grade_percent": null,
        "letter_grade": null
      },
      {
        "grade_date": null,
        "grade_type": null,
        "grade_percent": null,
        "letter_grade": null
      }
    ]
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="course in ctrl.subjectCourseGrades | filter: {selected  : true} track by $index">
      <table class="academy-table gpa-table">
        <tr ng-repeat="gpa in course.gpa" class="ots-data">
          <td>
            <b>Id is  : {{$index}}<span ng-bind="gpa.grade_date"></span></b>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its an Array, i tried your code at the beginning, its not showing records in Loop.

Comment: @Developer, As per updated code `ng-repeat="gpa in course.gpa"` should work, Test once with removing  _ng-if="!ctrl.editAcademyToggle"_

Comment: Yes i Tried, when i check `{{course.gpa | json}}` its coming, when i try `{{gpa | json}}` inside loop its not showing anything

Comment: Can Update your Code Snippet with my json Object.

Comment: @Developer, Sure; can you share the _subjectCourseGrades_ data structure? see the updated snippet

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$index` from ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="gpa in course.gpa" ng-if="!ctrl.editAcademyToggle" class="ots-data">
            <td>
                <b>Id is  : {{$index}}<span ng-bind="gpa.grade_date"></span></b>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Edit1 : After looking to your question, it seems you are using controller as instead $scope. You need this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="gpa in ctrl.course.gpa"></tr>
```

Edit 2:  div is not a valid table element. This may be the reason for not working. Use tbody .

```
<tbody ng-repeat="course in ctrl.subjectCourseGrades| filter: {selected  : true} track by $index">
    <tr ng-repeat="gpa in course.gpa" ng-if="!ctrl.editAcademyToggle" class="ots-data">
        <td>
            <b>Id is  : {{$index}}<span ng-bind="gpa.grade_date"></span></b>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Why you are using div inside table. Div is not a valid table element. This may be the reason for not working